# How to rerun Logstash jdbc input plugin?

Tags: logstash

I am using **logstash 2.3** in an **Ubuntu 14.04** , not as a service ( just extracted the tar.gz ). I successfully ran logstash jdbc input plug-in and fetched some data from my SQL server. Now I wanna re run the same, I forgot to set `record_last_run` to **fals**e during the test run.

When I try to re run it logstash is still standing. How can I get it to read the data again?

I tried to `locate .logstash_jdbc_last_run` with no luck in **/home** , **/root** and even **/tmp**. When I `echo $USER_HOME` it shows an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `clean_run` to `true`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-clean_run

> `clean_run`
>
> - Value type is boolean
> - Default value is false
>
> Whether the previous run state should be preserved

Comment: While i did the test run i forgot to set these params like clean run or metadata file path. The problem is that now I want to re run it now and am not able to do that. while running it again I tried to set the clean_run and it still did not read the db again.

Comment: input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "conn string"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_password => "yyy"
    clean_run => true
    statement => "SELECT * from le_master"
    last_run_metadata_path => "/home/neil/lastrun.txt"
  }
}
output {
 elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                 index => "le_master"
                 document_type  => "master"
                }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}